# How to set body attribute in css using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm setting the background image of a page using :

```
body {
    background: url(http://momentumbooks.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/space.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I would like to read a property from a scoped variable in my controller that looks like this:

```
$scope.image="http://momentumbooks.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/space.jpg"
```

How can I set this css body attribute from within my .html page ? In jQuery I could .css(). Can I do something similar using angulalJs?  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.css-styling doesn't seem to detail this ?

I'm trying this fiddle but does not work :

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3015/

fiddle code :

```
<body ng-style="getBodyStyle()">
</body>

$scope.getBodyStyle = function () {
    return {background: "url(http://momentumbooks.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/space.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;"};
};
```

Comment: Can you use regular old js? `document.body.style.background = url(variable);` or `document.body.style.backgroundImage = url(variable);`

Comment: @brouxhaha: Unless you have a _function_ called `url` defined that returns the proper syntax, you might want to add appropriate quotes …

Comment: @CBroe, yep, good point. `= 'url(' + variable + ')';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an app & controller before you can do anything- your JSFiddle is failing because you've got no controller, and you never define $scope.

You can create a $scope variable called $scope.bodyStyle in a controller, like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.bodyStyle = {background: "url(http://momentumbooks.com.au/wp-    content/uploads/2013/06/space.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed"};
});
```

And then register the app & the controller in the mark-up like this:

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-style="bodyStyle">
 Demo text
</body>

</html>
```

I made a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7cwAeGMsCYA8HIrWbl7d?p=preview) showing the whole app, because JSFiddle is a pain with Angular.

Angular needs to start with a lot more pieces working together than regular JS or JQuery- it can be confusing when you get started, so I recommend starting out with the [AngularJS seed app](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

You mention that you want to get the background image from a $scope variable. You could do that like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.image="http://momentumbooks.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/space.jpg";
  $scope.bodyStyle = {background: "url(" + $scope.image + ") no-repeat center center fixed"};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
<body ng-style="getBodyStyle()">`
```

and

```
$scope.getBodyStyle = function () {
    return {background: myData};
};
```

Comment: I've tried your code in a fiddle but does not work? Please see question update

Comment: It seems like you don't understand the basics of angular. You need a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what I did is call API to return image URL in state `resolve`:

```
resolve: {
   'image': ['$http', function($http) {
        return $http.get('/api/image');
    }]
}
```

The API returns JSON:

```
res.json({url: 'someUrl'});
```

Then you inject that to controller and in controller just call:

```
angular.element('body').css('background-image', 'url(\'' + image.data.url + '\')');
```

This seems clean to me as it does not need to inject `$scope` into controller which became a no-no recently.